Logical intepretation of "natural" and "canonical"
We are familiar with the example where $ V $ is an $ n $-dimensional vector space. It is well-known that both $ V^* $ and $ V^{**} $ are also $ n $-dimensional, hence $ V $, $ V^* $, and $ V^{**} $ are linearly isomorphic.
A familiar conclusion is that we can construct a "natural" or "canonical" linear isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^{**} $ defined by
$$
x \mapsto \tau(x)
$$
such that for $ f \in V^* $,
$$
\tau(x)(f) = f(x).
$$
This does not seem surprising. What is truly perplexing is that we sometimes encounter comments stating that we cannot construct a "natural" linear isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^* $. Of course, given a basis $ \{ e_i \} $ for $ V $ and the dual basis $ \{ e_i^* \} $ for $ V^* $, we can define a linear isomorphism $ e_i \mapsto e_i^* $. However, this isomorphism depends on the choice of basis, and thus is not "natural."
I believe many people share this confusion about what "natural" or "canonical" means. Is there a strict definition we can provide? Can we prove that there is no "natural" isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^* $ based on this definition? I have found some related MSE questions, such as this one, this one, and this one.
I know there is the concept of "natural transformation" in category theory, and indeed the constructed isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^{**} $ is a type of natural transformation. Many people use "natural transformation" to explain the meaning of "natural" mentioned at the beginning of this discussion.
Specifically, we certainly cannot construct a natural transformation from $ V $ to $ V^* $; it simply does not make sense. This is because the two functors involved are covariant and contravariant, which does not fit the premise for natural transformations. This is also what Eric Wofsey pointed out in this answer.
A "Logical" Intepretation?
However, I do not believe that the explanation using "natural transformations" from category theory completely dispels my doubts. I think my understanding of "natural" should come from a mathematical logic perspective: given some premise, if I can uniquely define an object based on that information, then that object is "natural" or "canonical".
For example, given a three-dimensional linear space $ V $, we know there are many elements in $ V $, but the only element that can be uniquely specified is $ 0 $. Therefore, $ 0 $ is the only "natural" element in $ V $.
In contrast, every element in $ \mathbb{R}^3 $ is "natural". For instance, vectors like $ [0, 4, 5] $ and $ [-1, 1.4, 7] $ can be uniquely characterized.
Returning to the finite-dimensional linear space $ V $, we know there are many linear maps from $ V $ to $ V^{**} $; in particular, we have constructed $ \tau $. Therefore, $ \tau $ is a "natural" linear map. Moreover, for any $ c \in \mathbb{R} $, $ c \tau $ is also a "natural" linear map. I assert that according to my "mathematical logic" definition, there are no other "natural" linear maps from $ V $ to $ V^{**} $ beyond these.
Regarding the earlier statement that we cannot construct a "natural" linear isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^* $, I provide an explanation using the "mathematical logic" definition of "natural". We know there are infinitely many linear maps from $ V $ to $ V^* $, but the only "natural" mapping is the zero map. The mapping $ e_i \mapsto e_i^* $ we constructed relies on additional information (the basis $ \{ e_i \} $). Based solely on the information in $ V $, we cannot uniquely construct an isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^* $.
In contrast, every linear map from $\mathbb R^n$ to its dual is "natural".
My Question:
At least for me, the above explanation alleviates my confusion about the concept of "natural." However, I am curious if there truly exists such a notion of "natural" in mathematical logic. What further conclusions can we draw about this concept? Are there any textbooks we can refer to?
In particular, if there is indeed such a "natural" concept in mathematical logic, I believe it would involve some "higher-order" expression. For example, the statement "there is no natural linear isomorphism from $ V $ to $ V^* $" should be considered a "meta-theorem", rather than an ordinary theorem. Simply using the language of axiomatic set theory may not suffice to prove or even express it, and I hope to learn more about this topic.

You are talking about definable objects. There is plenty of research about them: that is half of what model theory is about.
